# Лишний текст при парсинге сайта с помощью htmlagilitypack c#

Tags: c#, html, htmlagilitypack, span

Из вот этого хотел забрать только текст "Воздушный замок", но при попытке парисинга всегда забирает полностью и получается "Воздушный замокТекст". Если парсить по div и h1 все равно так же будет. Может как то можно сделать исключение, чтобы он пропускал span. Просто вырезать не хотел, так как в разных книгах, это по разному. Например: PDF,Аудио,Текст. Я не смог найти. Снизу приведу пример, как я пытался сделать и работало не правильно.

```
<div class="biblio_book_name biblio-book__title-block">
<h1 itemprop="name">Воздушный замок
<span class="label label-text">Текст</span>
</h1>
</div>
```

1 способ

```
HtmlNode name = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@itemprop='name']");
```

2 способ

```
HtmlNode name = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='biblio_book_name biblio-book__title-block']");
```

Comment: Ну вам что нужно? Найти у нужной ноды текст, так? Ну так и пишите `/text()` в конце первого примера.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо. Сработало. `"//h1[@itemprop='name']/text()"`

Comment: Советую в [закладки добавить](https://devhints.io/xpath). Ответ можете написать сами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было в конце первого способа написать `/text()`, чтобы получилось вот так `HtmlNode name = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@itemprop='name']/text()");`